# How to send email notifications to multiple assignees "Assigned to" without using Designer?

Tags: email, notifications

I have created one task and want to assign the task to multiple users. Put in 3 names under the "Assigned to" field but only the first name is able to receive email notifications. Under my workflow settings, i have ticked the option to send email to "include Task Assigned To". How to send the email notification to all assignees instead of only the first?

When I reassigned the case to another person, that person couldn't receive any email notifications as well. The server on which SP is installed does not have Designer enabled. Please help.

Comment: If you have SP 2013 then you can also enable "E-mail Notification" on task list. which will send emails to assignedTo users after task assigned or changed.